# https://www.mydomain.com and https://mydomain.com go to different pages

Tags: iis-6, http-redirect

Web Server: IIS 6.0 (ASP.Net 4.0)

I host two sites: one is the main web site and the other is the store site. Each are separate web sites in IIS. Each share the same wildcard SSL certificate. The store site uses a Host Header (`store.mydomain.com`) to direct traffic to it.

I want it so any URL used without the sub-domain "store" directs the user to the main web site, not the store web site.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the following URL always directs users to the default.aspx page on the store web site:

`https://www.mydomain.com`

Yet, these URLs correctly go to the main page on the main web site:

`http://mydomain.com`

`http://www.mydomain.com`

`https://mydomain.com`

What's up with the `https://www` that directs users to different page?

I have added a rewrite rule in the web.config file for both sites but it doesn't have any effect:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Consistent Domain" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure this is IIS6?  The URLRewrite feature is part of IIS7 and would have no effect under IIS6 if present.  If this is IIS6 that may well be the answer to your question.

That aside, it is difficult to answer this based on the data given.  It is possible that the bindings of the sites is incorrect and resulting in the traffic going to a site you don't expect.

Comment: Thanks for the response David. Yes, I'm certain it's IIS6. The OS is Windows Server 2003. I wasn't aware that the rewrite rule was only for IIS7 so that solution is a mute point and it's no wonder it didn't change the result. As far as "bindings of the sites", do you mean from the domain registrar point of view? I don't manage the domains so I can't say for certain how those are setup. if you want to experience the actual site and issue, just replace "mydomain" with "mydatatags".

Comment: Actaually, by bindings I meant the actual IIS configuration for which site listens on which IP/Port/HostHeader value.  I have run into cases where we thought one site was listening on port 443 and it turned out a different site was instead - very confusing until we reviewed the bindings and saw which site we were actually hitting.

Comment: I have both sites assigned to the same IP address and both are listening on port 443, but the "store" site uses a HostHeader (store.mydatatags.com) whereas the main site does not. I guess I thought using a URL without the sub-domain portion "store" would always direct users to the main site regardless if they used http or https with or without www. Something is in conflict, and most likely a setting in IIS but I'm not sure what to do.